# How to Find Which Columns in Postgres Table Are Aggregatable Relative to Other Columns?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    date_column DATE,
    customer_id INT,
    customer_group_id INT,
    column1 INT,
    column2 INT,
    column3 INT,
    column4 INT,
    column5 INT,
    spend DECIMAL(10, 2)
);
```

I know it to be true about the data that each of the values `column1`, `column2`, etc, as well as `customer_group_id` are unique to each `date_column` + `customer_id`. They're at *customer level*. I want the `spend` for each `date_column` + `customer_id`, as well as all the other columns. This is easily achieved with a `group by` like:

```
select date_column, customer_id, column1, ..., column5, sum(spend) group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

Okay, next I want to aggregate everything to *customer_group* level, so that I find the `spend` for every `date_column` + `customer_group_id` column. But where the problem is: I want to keep as many of the other columns as possible, without directly knowing which columns are genuinely at *customer_group* level. For example, if I knew, perhaps, that `column1` is unique to each `date_column` + `customer_group_id`, but none of the others are, I would do:

```
select date_column, customer_group_id, column1, sum(spend) 
group by 1, 2, 3
```

My question is: how can I programmatically (using sql) determine which columns to group on? Assume there are ~200 columns `column1, column2, ..., column200`, and *any number of them* could be unique to `date_column` + `customer_group_id`, and I want *all* columns which are.

Comment: Are you sure you're using PostgreSQL? `AUTO_INCREMENT` is a keyword in MySQL, not PostgreSQL. What do you get when you run the query `SELECT VERSION();`?

Comment: besides , use dynamic sql to get the columns needed, which criteria you have

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if you're using MySQL or PostgreSQL. But the answer is the same for both.

You ask how can you put unaggregated columns in the select-list when your query does GROUP BY. For that, the unaggregated column must be functionally dependent on the grouping column(s).

Columns are functionally dependent only on the primary key of the table. So you can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.table_constraints where table_schema='test';
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
| CONSTRAINT_CATALOG | CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA | CONSTRAINT_NAME | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE | ENFORCED |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
| def                | test              | PRIMARY         | test         | my_table   | PRIMARY KEY     | YES      |
+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+----------+
```

Since your columns `(date_column, customer_group_id)` do not comprise the primary key, other columns cannot be functionally dependent on them.

It doesn't matter if *you* know that these columns are unique within your data. The RDBMS cannot infer that.

```
mysql> select date_column, customer_group_id, column1, sum(spend) 
  from my_table group by 1, 2;

ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains 
nonaggregated column 'test.my_table.column1' which is not functionally dependent on 
columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

PostgreSQL reports a similar error under the same conditions:

```
postgres=# select date_column, customer_group_id, column1, sum(spend) 
  from my_table group by 1, 2;

ERROR:  column "my_table.column1" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select date_column, customer_group_id, column1, sum(spend) f...
                                               ^
```

To use these columns unaggregated in your select-list, you would have to group by the primary key of the table.

[MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/group-by-handling.html) says:

> SQL:1999 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns: If such a relationship exists between name and custid, the query is legal. **This would be the case, for example, were custid a primary key of customers.**

[PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) says:

> When GROUP BY is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions or when the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. **A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column.**

(emphasis mine)